# Chrome extension description repeating text

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to publish a Chrome extension but I'm having trouble with what seems like a glitch (or a case of extremely poor documentation) regarding the description section. Whatever text gets put in the box gets repeated at the top, with all whitespace reduced to a single space. I notice some published extensions have this in their description to.

I've tried using markdown (`#test`) or entering down with two lines, to indicate that it's some sort of title section, but no luck. I thought maybe the top part was a separate preview for HTML (because I know that has a similar behaviour with regards to collapsing whitespace) but `<span>test</span>` was rendered literally in both spots. I can't find anything about this issue online either.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens if you don't have a `description` field in the `manifest.json`. That top line is populated with the text in the description field.